# Indentação e quebra de linha em dados do sql para html

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados, front-end

Em resumo, criei uma tabela com tipo text no sql para que o usuario possa salvar algum conteúdo. 
Porem ao puxa-lo denovo para o HTML a formatação se perde.

Para sanar isso eu pensei em utilizar a tag < pre >, mas a tag < pre > enche meu layout de bugs, como recuo grande demais apenas no primeiro paragrafo, e não quebra a linha se o texto for grande demais, ele expande a largura da pagina. Tem alguma forma própria para manter essa formatação do texto?

Ps. o codigo em questão deverá retornar registros diversos, então não tem como prever onde a quebra de linha vai aparecer. A imagem abaixo foi so um registro aleatório para teste

[image: Texto formatado na tag <PRE>]

Segue abaixo o codigo backend utilizado:

entrada:

```
$query = $conect -> query( 'INSERT INTO textos (texto) VALUES({$_POST['texto']}')');
```

saida:

```
$query = $conect -> query("SELECT * FROM textos");
```

no html / php:

```
while ($temp = $query->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
     <div><pre>
          <?PHP echo $temp['texto']; ?>
      </pre></div>
<?php}  ?>
```

Comment: Que linguagem de backend está usando?

Comment: Backend estou usando PHP.

Comment: Poste seu codigo `php` então para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Meu php nao tem nada demais... Um textarea sendo postado atravez d um form..  e sendo recuperado através d um select. Vou postar.

Comment: A questão não é o que tem seu `php` e sim para podermos lhe ajudar, temos que ver o que foi feito.

Comment: Código postado.

Comment: basta usar o `<p></p>`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68406/discussion-between-amauri-and-rafael-augusto).